# Problem with kv file in visual studio code

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio Code for python and everything is good except Kivy.

I have simple code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and simple kivy file

```
    #:kivy
<MyGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                multinline:False

            Label:
                text: "Email: "

            TextInput:
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
```

And when I'm trying to run python file I got

*kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "c:\Users\Paweł\Documents\projects vscode\WeatherProject\my.kv", line 1:
1:#:kivy
2::
3:GridLayout:
Unknown directive*

Google isn't helpful at all. Please tell me what should I do.

Comment: did you install Kivy in your python environment?

Comment: Yes I did, I also installed kivy in VSCode

Comment: The first line is incorrect, Kivy language version is missing, e.g `#:kivy 1.0`, `#:kivy 1.11`, ...

Comment: I changed it, now it is #:kivy 1.11.0 and still the same problem

Comment: Did you save the .kv file after editing? Your code is correct now (fix indentation of first line, but it is not an error)

Comment: It is now official - I'm an idiot. I haven't saved the file after editing :)
Thank you soooo much, I've wasted a couple of hours to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should fix it!

```
MyGrid:

  <MyGrid>:
      GridLayout:
          cols:1
          size: root.width, root.height

          GridLayout:
              cols:2

              Label:
                  text: "Name: "

              TextInput:
                  multinline:False

              Label:
                  text: "Email: "

              TextInput:
                  multiline:False

          Button:
              text:"Submit"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you explain a bit more why the version in the question is wrong and why your version should work?

Comment: Dude, I created this post almost 2 years ago XD And I let you all know that I had solved the problem - I hadn't had VSCode set up correctly and it hadn't been saving files properly. But thanks, I'll give you upvote :D

Comment: @PawełDługosz ... this is what you get if you don't post an answer and the question remains open in combination with not reading the comments; and people focus on "no answers yet.. lets contribute". See my posted wiki. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from the OPs comment: I haven't saved the file after editing :)

Answer (score -1):

remove the indent from
GridLayout:

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31036314)